# Unmounted /boot, deleted from /etc/fstab, from where exactly GRUB take its settings?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I unmounted and removed the entry line in /etc/fstab regarding my /boot partition. The hero of all Unix questions Gilles [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125183/is-boot-partition-needed-after-os-is-booted) actually mentions this:

"No, /boot isn't needed during normal system operation. **In fact, it doesn't need to be mounted at all, since only the bootloader reads /boot, not Linux itself**. You can add noauto to the /boot line in your /etc/fstab"

I rebooted the OS - VM Fedora 22, and everything is working. I do not care about the updates and how that might mess it, my simple question is:

How does the GRUB knows from where to take its settings, knowing that I have removed /boot ?

Answer (score 5):

GRUB *doesn't* know that you've removed `/boot`.  During the boot process GRUB loads long before the kernel and always has to figure out what's going on without the convenience of things like mounted filesystems.  When you install GRUB it's told where (as in the BIOS or EFI partition) to find it's config file.  It isn't until long after GRUB has handed off to the kernel that the `/etc/fstab` file is loaded and filesystems are mounted.

Comment: It does and I did, but I need at least 15 reputation points to change the publicly displayed post score.